"Chrisma" and "Him"
The Greek noun χρῖσμα (chrisma) = "anointing/unction" occurs in two related verses in 1 John 2 as follows:

V20: And you have anointing from the Holy [One], and all of you know.
V27: And you, the anointing that you received from Him abides in you, and you have no need that anyone should teach you. But just as the same anointing teaches you concerning all things and is true and is no lie, and just as it has taught you, you shall abide in Him.

In V20 the origin of the anointing is from the "Holy [One]".  In V27, the origin of this anointing is from "Him".
Now, V24 & 25 appear to offer the antecedent for the pronoun "Him" in V27 -

As for you, let what you have heard from the beginning remain in you.
If it does, you will also remain in the Son and in the Father. 25And
this is the promise that He Himself made to us: eternal life.

Thus, the antecedent of "Him" in V27 appears to be either the Father or the Son, but more likely the Son.
QUESTION: Who provides the anointing in 1 John 2:20-27?  Is it:

The Father?
The Son?
The Holy Spirit?

[I note that there are numerous precedents for each of these being given the title/adjective "holy" elsewhere in the NT.]


20 But you have been anointed by the Holy One, and you all have knowledge.
-1 John 2:20

John's sparing allusions to the Holy One and the anointing are difficult, if not impossible, to decipher exclusively with any specificity from the letter itself so we may benefit from reviewing how John and other New Testament writers illuminate the objects of his allusions.
The Holy One:
The phrase "the Holy One" (as it is interpreted in English) is used 7 times in the New Testament outside of 1 John 2:

6 of the 7 times it refers to Jesus (John 6:69, Rev 3:7, Mark 1:24, Luke 4:34, Acts 2:27, Acts 13:3)
1 of 7 refers to the Lord God (Rev 16:5)

Most notably it is a title Jesus uses to refer to himself in John's Revelation:

7 “And to the angel of the church in Philadelphia write: ‘The words of the holy one, the true one, who has the key of David, who opens and no one will shut, who shuts and no one opens.
-Revelation 3:7

Perhaps Jesus is who we should be thinking of as the Holy One.
The Anointing:
John doesn't discuss directly the concept of anointing outside 1 John, however  Luke does where he reveals that the anointing of Christ is the Holy Spirit - (the anointing of the Anointed - the christening of the Christ):

37 you yourselves know what happened throughout all Judea, beginning from Galilee after the baptism that John proclaimed: 38 how God anointed Jesus of Nazareth with the Holy Spirit and with power. He went about doing good and healing all who were oppressed by the devil, for God was with him.
-Acts 10:37-38


18 “The Spirit of the Lord is upon me,
because he has anointed me
to proclaim good news to the poor.
-Luke 4:18

Further, Luke identifies Jesus as the proximate source to his disciples of the Holy Spirit he received from the Father:

33 Being therefore exalted at the right hand of God, and having received from the Father the promise of the Holy Spirit, he has poured out this that you yourselves are seeing and hearing.
-Acts 2:33

John also explains that while the Father is the ultimate source of the Holy Spirit, He will be sending it by way of His Son:

26 But the Helper, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, he will teach you all things and bring to your remembrance all that I have said to you. John 14:26


26 “But when the Helper comes, whom I will send to you from the Father, the Spirit of truth, who proceeds from the Father, he will bear witness about me. John 15:26

Thus, perhaps the anointing that we received from the Holy One is the Holy Spirit that we receive from Christ, the Holy One.
Conclusion
So if Jesus is the most frequent referent of the phrase "the Holy One" in the NT and the Holy Spirit is the anointing of Jesus and Jesus is the proximate source of the anointing or Holy Spirit we receive, then it seems likely that Jesus is the referent for the phrase Holy One in 1 John 2:20 and is the source of the anointing in the same verse that we can identify as the Holy Spirit...
That being said, the Lord God is also identified as the Holy One (Revelation 16:5) and the Father is the ultimate source of the Holy Spirit, so...
As to whether the Holy One refers to the Father or the Son, your guess is as good as mine concerning which of these John specifically had in mind as the source of the anointing (the Holy Spirit) that we receive, and perhaps this ambiguity between the role of the Father and of the Son is exactly what the Apostle John intended all along.

+1. Excellent analysis.  I also note that it is only Jesus who promises "eternal life" as per V25 which is presumable the same person as in V20 and 27?

"Holy [One]" also refers to Jesus in Luke 1:35.

@Dottard, thanks. With regard to Luke 1:35 I was going off  of the English translation of the ESV.  In the Greek, it doesn't seem to follow the exact same pattern as the other examples where the determiner is right next to the adjective, so thats why I didn't include it, but indeed many other translation do render it as the Holy one as you say.

In Luke 1:35 the adjective is usually connected to the participle τὸ γεννώμενον ⸆ ἅγιον.

I would say the "Holy Spirit." Unlike the false brethren, the true believers to whom John wrote had an "unction" or anointing which provided the ability to hold to the truth. "Unction" (Greek, chrisma) is a play on words--the false "christs" of vs18-19 are contrasted with the "chrisma" (empowered saints) of verse 20.
In the Old Testament kings, priests, and prophets were anointed with oil to symbolize the Holy Spirit was empowering them for their task. ( 1 Samuel 16:13 and Isaiah 61:1).
These verses speak of how the Holy Spirit anoints the believer so he will have knowledge which comes from God, the Holy One. Gnostic false teachers claimed to be the sole source of truth, but the Holy Spirit makes it possible for all believers to know the truth.
At verse 21 John did not write to convey hidden truths which had been concealed from his hearers; his letter was sent to people who simply needed to be reminded (like we all do) of things they already knew. They already knew the gospel, and when they recalled that no lie springs from that source of truth, they would recognize that truth and falsehood cannot coexist.

@Dottard I was simply addressing your basic question? "QUESTION: Who provides the anointing in 1 John 2:20-27? Is it "The Father, the Son, the Holy Spirit?"

Why does John 16 use many masculine pronouns for the Spirit?

@TheChaz2.0 After doing a little research I found the following. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6000/how-do-we-know-to-refer-to-the-holy-spirit-as-he

Robertson gives significant evidence for the Holy Spirit.

But followers of Christ do have “the oil of anointing” (το ἐλαιον του χρισματος [to elaion tou chrismatos], Ex. 29:7), the Holy Spirit. This word in the N. T. only here and verse 2:27. Later the term was applied to baptism after baptismal remission came to be taught (Tertullian, etc.). From the Holy One (ἀπο του ἁγιου [apo tou hagiou]).
--
Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (1 John 2:20). Broadman Press.

This commentary appears to present the prominent views:

Many commentators hold that the “anointing” (v. 27) is the Spirit (cf. Jn 14:17, 26; Acts 10:38); others suggest that it refers in context to the word, the message of the gospel; in either case it alludes to the Old Testament practice of God setting particular people apart for his calling, which here applies to all believers. The Old Testament used anointing oil symbolically to consecrate or separate people (such as kings) or objects (such as the tabernacle) for sacred use. The ultimate consecration for such use arose when the Spirit came on people (Is 61:1; cf. 1 Sam 10:1, 9; 16:13).
--
Keener, C. S. (1993). The IVP Bible background commentary: New Testament (1 John 2:24–27). InterVarsity Press.

The masculine can be used for the Holy Spirit.  For example, ἐκεῖνος in:

Ταῦτα λελάληκα ὑμῖν παρʼ ὑμῖν μένων·  ὁ δὲ παράκλητος, τὸ πνεῦμα τὸ ἅγιον, ὃ πέμψει ὁ πατὴρ ἐν τῷ ὀνόματί μου, ἐκεῖνος ὑμᾶς διδάξει πάντα καὶ ὑπομνήσει ὑμᾶς πάντα ἃ εἶπον ὑμῖν [ἐγώ].
(John 14:25–26, NA28)

and

Ὅταν ⸆ ἔλθῃ ὁ παράκλητος ὃν ἐγὼ ⸀πέμψω ὑμῖν παρὰ τοῦ πατρός,* τὸ πνεῦμα τῆς ἀληθείας ὃ παρὰ τοῦ πατρὸς ἐκπορεύεται, ἐκεῖνος μαρτυρήσει περὶ ἐμοῦ·
(John 15:26, NA28)


This is the majority view which is OK.  But it does not address the other matters raised in the question such as "holy" being masculine - if this is true, then it is the only place when masculine "holy" refers to the neuter "spirit".

Doesn't the neuter genitive singular have the same form as the masculine for τοῦ ἁγίου?

My apologies for not recognizing this.  You are completely correct. - same with "Him".  I will correct the question.

Some would argue that ἐκεῖνος refers back to the masculine Παράκλητος in John 15:26 and 16:13 and 14:26.  In the latter case, ὃ (whom) definitely refers to the neuter Holy Spirit.
